# Architectural Flow of Angular 2 app

Tags: architecture, angular, interaction, angular2-services

I am working on an Angular2 application. My App is either used to create a new post or edit an already created post. It has two pages.

First Page, Is just a normal form with all basic Info and second page has multiple components which will talk to each other i.e. each component is in a way interlinked to each other and need to talk to each other. And these components are dynamic depending on type.

**My Question is: How should I architect the flow of the application so that it fits both create and edit scenarios.


The Way I am thinking of right now is,**

Each component has a service(make them injectable) which will hold the data and I have to create observers for all those services and subscribe to those in other components so they will act depending upon changes in service.

**Other way is:**

I created a common emitter service which will return emit objects, I can call that component and emit an event which other components listen to.

**Which way would be a good way of dealing with this kind of scenarios, and help in the long run? Also, Should help in a way so that I can later add few more components seamlessly?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would consider to create the 'model' objects you need in the ngOnInit method of the second page and pass them as input to the components which need them.

This requires that the components define @Input() properties to receive such 'model' objects.

I hope this helps

**IN RESPONSE TO THE COMMENT OF ANUTEJA**

I would consider the following strategy:

1) `Child1` defines an output property (let's say `@Output() resultOutput`) through which it signals the fact that new results have been retrieved from the backend call, i.e. something like `this.resultOutput.emit(resultOfBackendCall)` (assuming that `resultOfBackendCall` is a variable defined in the method of `Child1` that retrieves the data)

2) `Parent` component subscribes to the `resultOutput` property of `Child1` and therefore knows when a new result is fetched, via something like `<child1 (resultOutput)="newResult($event)"></child1>`

3) The `newResult(event)` method of `Parent` stores the result received from `Child1` into a property of `Parent` (let's call the variable `resultReceived`), something like

```
newResult(resultFromBackEnd) {
  this.resultReceived = resultFromBackEnd;
}
```

4) `Child2` defined an input property (let's say `@Input() myList`) where it expects to receive from `Parent` the list that needs to be displayed

5) `Parent` feeds `Child2` using the property `resultReceived` via something like `<child2 [myList]="resultReceived"></child2>`

If everything works, as soon as `Parent` receives notification from `Child1` of a new result from backend call it feeds `Child2` and the result should be diplayed.

Basically this means that `Parent` centralizes all notifications and dispatches data to its children according to application rules. This way, in my opinion, you obtain a clear design with `Parent` orchestrating what happens in this particular piece of Application.

I hope this is clear enough and that it helps